# Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings on upgrading to NativeScript 6.0

Tags: nativescript-angular

For my existing 5.3.2 Nativescript, when I tried to upgrade to NativeScript 6.0 to incorporate a plugin, I am unable to launch the application in the emulator

I have already rectified any red line errors in the build process. These errors were strangely related to including all TS files in the tsconfig.json file that I did not ever have to do earlier.

```
The build result is located at: C:\Users\xxx\git\xxx\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Installing on device xx.xx.xx.xx:5555...
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'xx.xx.xx.xx:5555'.
Restarting application on device xx.xx.xx.xx:5555...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.xxx on device 192.168.24.102:5555.
ActivityManager: Start proc 7559:org.nativescript.xxx/u0a66 for activity org.nativescript.xxx/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
JS: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.xxx/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.xxx/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:19)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
System.err:     ... 9 more
ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.xxx(pid 7559) has died
```

While there are no errors in the build, installation & syncing process, I don't understand how to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow those steps (Android/iOS):

1. Remove node_modules using this command :- **Android:- rm node_modules** Or
   **iOS:- rm -rf node_moduels**
2. Remove hooks using this command:- **rm hooks / rm -rf hooks**
3. Remove platforms using this command:- **rm platforms / rm -rf platforms**
   Or 
   **tns platform remove android/ios**.
4. Again Install the npm  using:- **npm install**.
5. Add the platform in your project:- **tns platform add android/ios**
6. Again run your project:- **tns run android/ios --bundle**